# Talk to a customer/ talk with a customer

Tags: idioms, prepositions

what's the difference between the two expressions I stated in the title?

I am guessing that "talk to a customer" is more common, because when I google them there are many more results for that. But "talk with a customer" shouldn't be "incorrect" neither.

Please let me know!

Comment: It's implicit in the general significance of the preposition that if you talk ***with*** someone it's more likely to be a two-way interaction (perhaps between *equal* parties), whereas if you talk ***to*** them this is more likely to apply when you are the boss (perhaps you're telling *them* something, but not really seeking feedback). In the more extreme case someone might complain that you're talking ***at*** them (in which context they mean you're not listening to *anything* they might have to say).

Comment: ...so the boss of a customer support department could quite reasonably say *I'll talk **to** my staff and tell them they should always refer to "talking **with** the customer" when writing up reports.*

Comment: To me (as a British English speaker), the primary difference is that "talk with" sounds American to me.

Comment: Yes, the Brits are always sorting things out. :)

Comment: @ColinFine I agree. This is entirely a question of geographical location. For me, *speaking with someone* is like singing a duet. As far as I'm concerned we British converse by speaking to one another.

Comment: Thanks everyone, my question has been solved! It was also nice to know the British style.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have stated, 'talking with a customer' could be seen as less formal, less directional (you can and the customer could be talking about your favorite sports teams, collectively). Talking to a customer could be seen much more directional, think about a police office talking to a group of people, or mother talking to her child. There are slight differences between these two expressions but either of them are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I feel it when we use talk to it is in common way or no purpose.
When we use talk with it means intended or purpose of discussing or getting clarity from.